# Permuting entire rows in a 2d numpy array

Tags: numpy, permutation

Consider numpy array `arr` , shown below:

```
    arr = ([[1, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7],
            [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
            [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
            [4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

I want to find all row permutations of `arr`.   **NOTE: the order of  elements in any given row is unchanged.  It is the entire rows that are being permuted.**

Because `arr` has 5 rows, there will be 5! = 120 permutations.    I’m hoping these could be ‘stacked’ into a 3d array `p`, having shape (120, 5, 6):

```
p = [[[1, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7],
      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
      [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],  
      [4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8],
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]],

     [[1, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7],
      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
      [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],  
      [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
      [4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8]],

       … etc …

     [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      [4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8],
      [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],  
      [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
      [1, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7]]]
```

There is a lot of material online about permitting elements within rows, but I need help in permuting the entire rows themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
from itertools import permutations
out = np.array([arr[np.argsort(idx)] for idx in permutations(range(5))])

print(out)

[[[1 5 6 3 3 7]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [1 2 3 4 5 6]]

 [[1 5 6 3 3 7]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [1 2 3 4 5 6]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]]

 [[1 5 6 3 3 7]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [1 2 3 4 5 6]]

 ...

 [[1 2 3 4 5 6]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [1 5 6 3 3 7]]

 [[4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [1 2 3 4 5 6]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [1 5 6 3 3 7]]

 [[1 2 3 4 5 6]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [1 5 6 3 3 7]]]
```

Comment: That's a great solution with minimal imports!

Comment: Excellent - does the job nicely

Answer (score 1):

Similar answer, but you do not need to .argsort one more time

```py
from itertools import permutations
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 5, 6, 3, 3, 7],
                [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
                [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                [4, 8, 4, 8, 4, 8],
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
output = np.array([arr[i, :] for i in permutations(range(5))])
print(output)

[[[1 5 6 3 3 7]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [1 2 3 4 5 6]]

 [[1 5 6 3 3 7]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [1 2 3 4 5 6]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]]

 [[1 5 6 3 3 7]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [1 2 3 4 5 6]]

 ...

 [[1 2 3 4 5 6]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [1 5 6 3 3 7]]

 [[1 2 3 4 5 6]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [1 5 6 3 3 7]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]]

 [[1 2 3 4 5 6]
  [4 8 4 8 4 8]
  [0 1 0 1 0 1]
  [2 2 2 2 2 2]
  [1 5 6 3 3 7]]]
```

This is a bit faster, here are speed comparisons:

```py
%%timeit
output = np.array([arr[i, :] for i in permutations(range(5))])
381 µs ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
%%timeit
output = np.array([arr[np.argsort(idx)] for idx in permutations(range(5))])
863 µs ± 97.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: This is a great improvement in time.   Thank you.